Azure Application gateway IPs allowlist terraform
I have the following application gateway defined in terraform
resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "app_gateway" {
    name                = "agw-${local.application_context}"
    resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
    location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location
    ...

    sku {
     name     = "WAF_v2"
     tier     = "WAF_v2"
     capacity = 2
   }

   gateway_ip_configuration {
        name      = "agw-${local.application_context}"
        subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.snet.id
   }

   frontend_port {
     ....
   }
 
 .....

 waf_configuration {
   enabled                  = true
   firewall_mode            = "Prevention"
   rule_set_type            = "OWASP"
   rule_set_version         = "3.2"
   file_upload_limit_mb     = 100
   max_request_body_size_kb = 128
   request_body_check       = false
 }
}

I am struggling to understand how to set an IPs allowlist in order to allow only specific IPs to connect to my Application Gateway.

To allow IPs in an application gateway, there are two ways: one is using an NSG, and the other is using a WAF policy
Here is the updated Terraform code to allow IPs in the application gateway using a WAF Policy

Note: To create WAF policy you need to create a application gateway with SKU WAF V2

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rgname" {
  location = "eastus"
  name     = "sample-rg-appgateway"
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "samplepublicip" {
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  location            = "eastus"
  name                = "demopublicip"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rgname.name
  sku                 = "Standard"
  zones               = ["1"]
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_resource_group.rgname,
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "samplevnet" {
  address_space       = ["10.1.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rgname.location
  name                = "samplevnet"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rgname.name
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_public_ip.samplepublicip,
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "appsubnet" {
  address_prefixes     = ["10.1.0.0/24"]
  name                 = "samplesubnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rgname.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.samplevnet.name
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_virtual_network.samplevnet,
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_web_application_firewall_policy" "appgateway" {
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rgname.location
  name                = "appgatewaypolicy"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rgname.name
  custom_rules {
    action    = "Allow"
    name      = "AllowIP"
    priority  = 100
    rule_type = "MatchRule"
    match_conditions {
      match_values = ["125.19.127.99", "172.168.10.5", "192.168.10.0"]
      operator     = "IPMatch"
      match_variables {
        variable_name = "RemoteAddr"
      }
    }
  }
  managed_rules {
    managed_rule_set {
      version = "3.2"
    }
  }
  policy_settings {
    mode = "Detection"
  }
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_subnet.appsubnet,
  ]
}

locals {
  backend_address_pool_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.samplevnet.name}-beap"
  request_routing_rule_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.samplevnet.name}-rqrt"
}

resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "appgateway" {
  enable_http2        = true
  firewall_policy_id  = azurerm_web_application_firewall_policy.appgateway.id
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rgname.location
  name                = "demoappgateway"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rgname.name
  zones               = ["1"]
  autoscale_configuration {
    max_capacity = 10
    min_capacity = 0
  }
  backend_address_pool {
    name = local.backend_address_pool_name
  }
  backend_http_settings {
    cookie_based_affinity = "Disabled"
    name                  = "sampletarget" request_routing_rule
    port                  = 80
    protocol              = "Http"
    request_timeout       = 20
  }
  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = "appGwPublicFrontendIpIPv4"
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.samplepublicip.id
  }
  frontend_port {
    name = "port_80"
    port = 80
  }
  gateway_ip_configuration {
    name      = "appGatewayIpConfig"
    subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.appsubnet.id
  }
  http_listener {
    frontend_ip_configuration_name = "appGwPublicFrontendIpIPv4"
    frontend_port_name             = "port_80"
    name                           = "samplelistener"
    protocol                       = "Http"
  }
  request_routing_rule {
    backend_address_pool_name  = local.backend_address_pool_name
    backend_http_settings_name = "sampletarget" 
    http_listener_name         = "samplelistener"
    name                       = local.request_routing_rule_name
    priority                   = 100
    rule_type                  = "Basic"
  }
  sku {
    name = "WAF_v2"
    tier = "WAF_v2"
  }
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_web_application_firewall_policy.appgateway,
  ]
}

Terraform apply

After executing the Terraform code, the application gateway has been created with the WAF policy as shown below.

Reference: Custom rules for Web Application Firewall v2 on Azure Application Gateway
Application Gateway infrastructure configuration, if you are using NSG

thank you, I just add to adapt  action= "Block" and negation_condition = true in order to block all the other IPs and allow only mine.

Suppose you changed mode to "Prevention" and you wanted to allow traffic from any IP address but those three that you entered in, you want them to specifically be except from the rest owasp rules, how can you do that? Or in otherwords how can you Allow an IP and stop processing further rules?
